# CakePhp: Form validation on several fields?

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, model

I've some conditions to a form to be valid that has to be on several fields instead one, how to do this.

Some example for a registration:

```
enterprise or firstName+lastName filled
mobile phone number OR static phone number filled
```

How to do this? Is there an implemented way or I've to do it myself every time?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your own validation rules. Cake Book: [Custom validation rules](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1179/Custom-Validation-Rules)
Attach a rule to the enterprise field what checks if it is filled or the first, last names are filled. Attach another rule to the name fields to check if the names or the enterprise fields are filled. Similar to the phone fields. You are in the model so you can reach all passed fields in $this->data

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand the question correctly but you can create your own validation rule and then apply it for the desired fields (not really the other way around). [See here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1181/Adding-your-own-Validation-Methods)

Otherwise Cakephp has a lot of pre-built validation rules here is an example:

```
var $validate = array(
    'title' => array(
        'titleRule1' => array (
            'rule' => array('minLength', 1),
            'required' => true,
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'last' => true,
            'message' => 'Please enter a title.'
        ),
        'titleRule2' => array(
            'rule' => array('between', 1, 100),
            'message' => 'Your title must be between 1 and 100 characters long.'
        )
    ),
    'description' => array(
        'rule' => array('minLength', 1),
        'required' => true,
        'allowEmpty' => false,
        'last' => true,
        'message' => 'Please write a description.'
    )
);
```